# How to get acess to web-app via IP or localhost in NGINX?

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, server, localhost

I have a `Codeigniter` application on my `localhost`. I configured hosts file like this:

```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   127.0.0.1       myapp
```

So I can open my project with link 
`http://myapp/` 
But when I try open project via `http://localhost/myapp` or `http://192.168.1.10/myapp` it's not working. But with apache all is ok. I'd like to solve this problem on nginx.

My nginx config:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   root /var/www/nginx/myapp;
   index index.html index.htm index.php;

   server_name myapp www.myapp;

        location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location / {
                # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either the server block must be the *default server* or named in the `server_name` directive.

To make the server block the default server use:

```
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

Or extend your `server_name` directive to include all the names:

```
server_name myapp www.myapp localhost 192.168.1.10;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks, but after - any ajax request return an 404 error from server, not from CI errors manager. I think there are not any crossdomain requests.